# Oauth2 and Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have looked all over the stackoverflow, but until now, I have not figured out a complete solution. I have an authorization server (not Google, Facebook, GitHub etc) and my application will use authorization_code as grant-type. I have the

- authorization url
- Client-id
- Client-secret
- Token-uri
- Scope

And I cannot configure it to run. Also I need to refresh the token.
Every post that I found mixes the dependencies and the solutions. I just need to know proper setup/example of a client that calls authorization server and then uses this token to get resources from another server.

Thank you very much

Comment: even from your question it's not visible which versions of libraries are you using and what exactly is your problem. Pprovide some application shared on some public repository and somebody could be able to help you.

Comment: Both stackoverflow and spring-security documentation provide detailed answers for configuring OAuth2 clients in various scenarios.

Comment: As I saw there are migrations to libraries that have confused me. I didn’t find clear answer how I can with spring boot to implement oauth2 client with authorization code. I am not talking about a specific library here in order to be more easy to find a solution